Echarts endLabel doesn't clip on zoom
With Echarts, I dont know how clip the endLabel when I do zoom in the line and move at top or bottom, the endLabel should be clipped like the series is clipped.
With Echarts, I dont know how clip the endLabel when I do zoom in the line and move at top or bottom, the endLabel should be clipped like the series is clipped.
exemple: 
is there an option for that ?
// prettier-ignore
const data = [["2000-06-05", 116], ["2000-06-06", 129], ["2000-06-07", 135], ["2000-06-08", 86], ["2000-06-09", 73], ["2000-06-10", 85], ["2000-06-11", 73], ["2000-06-12", 68], ["2000-06-13", 92], ["2000-06-14", 130], ["2000-06-15", 245], ["2000-06-16", 139], ["2000-06-17", 115], ["2000-06-18", 111], ["2000-06-19", 309], ["2000-06-20", 206], ["2000-06-21", 137], ["2000-06-22", 128], ["2000-06-23", 85], ["2000-06-24", 94], ["2000-06-25", 71], ["2000-06-26", 106], ["2000-06-27", 84], ["2000-06-28", 93], ["2000-06-29", 85], ["2000-06-30", 73], ["2000-07-01", 83], ["2000-07-02", 125], ["2000-07-03", 107], ["2000-07-04", 82], ["2000-07-05", 44], ["2000-07-06", 72], ["2000-07-07", 106], ["2000-07-08", 107], ["2000-07-09", 66], ["2000-07-10", 91], ["2000-07-11", 92], ["2000-07-12", 113], ["2000-07-13", 107], ["2000-07-14", 131], ["2000-07-15", 111], ["2000-07-16", 64], ["2000-07-17", 69], ["2000-07-18", 88], ["2000-07-19", 77], ["2000-07-20", 83], ["2000-07-21", 111], ["2000-07-22", 57], ["2000-07-23", 55], ["2000-07-24", 60]];
const dateList = data.map(function (item) {
  return item[0];
});
const valueList = data.map(function (item) {
  return item[1];
});
option = {
    
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'slider',
      yAxisIndex: 0,
      filterMode: 'none'
    
    }
  ],
  // Make gradient line here
  visualMap: [
    {
      show: false,
      type: 'continuous',
      seriesIndex: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 400
    },
    {
      show: false,
      type: 'continuous',
      seriesIndex: 1,
      dimension: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: dateList.length - 1
    }
  ],
  title: [
    {
      left: 'center',
      text: 'Gradient along the y axis'
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      data: dateList
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {},
  ],
  grid: [
    {
      bottom: '60%'
    },
    {
      top: '60%'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      endLabel: {
        show: true,
        formatter: 'End Label of the serie-line'
      },
      showSymbol: false,
      data: valueList
    }
  ]
};

Here echarts the project
Here the sandbox project

Finally I get working using markLine, that was the purpose, here the label of markLine get clipped fine when Zoomed in.
here the code:
Echart player code exemple here
